# iPhone 5 Stuck in Recovery after IOS8 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, iphone, ios

My wife's iPhone 5 is now stuck in recovery after she tried to do a IOS8 update over the  air.  Of course she has no backup or anything like that, so this was an all or nothing upgrade.  She got to the "verifying install" and then it rebooted and put her in recovery mode.  I called apple support and their only suggestion was a complete restore and losing all her data.  Any suggestions on recovering data or possibly getting out of recovery mode?

By recovery mode I mean there is an iTunes logo with a charger and an up arrow pointing to the iTunes logo.  I'm assuming this mean plug your device into iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. The one easy solution is [ReiBoot](http://download.cnet.com/ReiBoot/3000-18553_4-76037571.html).

It's no scam and you can easily leave the recovery mode with just one click. After that, you can install it without further problems.

Comment: I've tried this. It just reboots the phone and I'm still in recovery mode.

Comment: I tried recboot as well